# Is this comma usage correct?

Tags: commas

When we hear about eating disorders, such as binge eating, anorexia, or bulimia, I usually don't know about it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the commas, but the sentence doesn’t make much sense. Why would we usually not know when we hear about eating disorders?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Uh sorry my bad about the logic. But yeah since I don't know about it then I'll change we to I.

Comment: With the edit, it makes even less sense! Now _you_ don’t know it when someone tells _us_ about eating disorders. Note that ‘it’ here refers back to hearing about eating disorders. If you want to refer to the eating disorders themselves, you have to use ‘them’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commas are fine, but the sentence itself needs a little editing. Try

> When we hear about eating disorders, such as binge eating, anorexia, or bulimia, we often do not understand much about them.

Comment: Uh yeah I edited.